# ASP.Net MVC vs. HTML + KnockoutJS + WebAPI

Tags: jquery, architecture, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm wondering why not just have static HTML files in an ASP.Net MVC 4 Web Project that use jQuery+jQuery Templates+KnockoutJS combination consuming REST based (ASP.Net MVC 4 WEB API hosted on Azure & secured using ACS).  The Web API can use Entity Framework and return JSON serialized objects that can be retrieved using $.ajax() and bound using KnockoutJS.

What is it that ASP.Net MVC (for the Web pages) provides that adds value to this architecture?
On top of my head, I can think of:

1. Multi device support (device detection and template replacement)
2. Server-side validations of submitted data (not sure as I can also put the validations on WEB API?)
3. I can still rewrite my URLs even if I'm using static html files (since I'm using ASP.Net MVC anyway).

Can someone help me understand this better?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is also important to note that KnockoutJS is _library_  a can be supplemented to your MVC project, and Microsoft is heavily embracing the technology. (Currently out of the Big CDN's, Microsoft is the only one to be hosting the knockout library.)

Comment: I don't think he's suggesting that MVC wouldn't work with Knockout.js, just wondering what value the framework would provide him that Knockout.js (and related JS libraries) does not already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Great question. I'm certainly finding that my MVC / Razor code is becoming less and less as I progress with my Knockout project, but I think I'll always have some aspects of the views which I want to be determined server-side.

Fundamental contextual stuff like whether to render a logged in / logged out panel in a layout page, role related decisions as to what should be accessible, etc. I guess if you were careful enough with your security and implement sufficient guard code on the server when someone actually tries to do something then you could achieve most of that in Knockout, but you'd probably end up with a huge amount of bloat, catering for every possible part of the view.

It probably depends on your application but I think for most web apps there's a fairly common sense division between what should be determined at server render time and what should be done on the client.

If nothing else, you may want links etc in your views to be indexed by search engines. If you pass down, say, your "latest 10 products" in JSON and render them with hyperlinks in a Knockout template, you'd lose out on that.

Comment: You're right.  There'd always be some aspects of views I want controlled [rendering of] on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

It is really a question of using the right tool for the job.

From what I can tell after doing development with knockout, it's real power comes from  observables and the real time DOM updates.  This makes a rich interface in client side applications quicker to create, and easier to manage.  However, it is still more time consuming and difficult to implement than working with straight Razor pages.  So Knockout JS is an advantage for certain applications where lots of data driven UI updates need to happen "ajaxically", but will be overkill for others.

Comment: +1. I too now live in the ajaxical kingdom of joy.

Answer (score 1):

If a client didn't have Javascript enabled in this scenario your site would be useless, and you would have no way to provide them a suitable alternative.

Using the MVC Framework and Razor syntax you could still build dynamically generated, data-driven content without the use of jQuery or AJAX.  MVC will provide you the clean separation of concerns between your Model and your View regardless of whether or not you have Javascript enabled.

Comment: I want to give this answer a -1 for the simple fact that, who disables javascript or owns and uses a device without javascript support these days?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that it's the most common scenario, and that's not really relevant.  The fact still remains that there are scenarios where a JS only page would be inaccessible to some users.  I myself worked on a web project with in the last two months that required a non-JS path through the content.  Just because there aren't a lot of people on IE6 doesn't mean that it still isn't a thorn in the side of many web developers tasked with 100% backwards-compatibility.

Comment: Ok, no -1. Thanks for the clarification. BTW, take a look at the link I posted in my answer, and send it to your higher-ups if you like. The **IE6 is dead already** section notes, jQuery2 is set to drop support for IE 8 and below.

Comment: IE 6 won't be dead until Microsoft stops supporting it, it doesn't matter when jQuery gives up on it.  Check out http://www.ie6countdown.com/, a site created by Microsoft, and you'll see there are still 6% of web users on IE6.  At any rate, the point is that a truly robust web application must be able to support users even on the fringe of compatibility scenarios.

Comment: I have a feeling that most of the people who use IE6 only use it because they have to use it for some specific China-related sites (government and banking). See this for reference: http://micgadget.com/11633/why-the-chinese-still-favour-internet-explorer-6/ They probably use other browsers for the rest of the web, or perhaps because some Chinese hackers just don't want to let IE6 go.

Answer (score 1):

Security is probably the number 1 advantage I see. You still have the structure ASP.NET behind it. Yes its true, in your views, you can certainly use razor syntax and have your view model rendered with Knockout, and JSON.NET makes data-binding easier than ever. Ultimately in the future, maybe MVC won't be part of the equation in the future? (check out Meteor js too, its wicked cool, and that type of dynamic model binding is just not possible with anything else *other* than javascript atm.)

Also if you want to see it in action, I found a good Codeproject with MVC and knockout. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424642/Customer-KnockoutJS-and-MVC-demo-using-JSON

Answer (score 1):

Here, [read this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/08/01/rich-javascript-applications-the-seven-frameworks-throne-of-js-2012). A quote from it:

> It’s no longer good enough to build web apps around full page loads
>   and then “progressively enhance” them to behave more dynamically.
>   Building apps which are fast, responsive and modern require you to
>   completely rethink your approach.

As to your question, what does MVC offer that adds value to an MVVM architecture? Catering custom content to different devices can be an advantage, but you can do this to a degree with CSS media queries too. The decision comes down to how many bytes you want to send from the server to the device.

You can do server-side validations without using MVC or WebAPI as well, and you don't need to use a ModelBinder or ModelState.IsValid to do it. Look into something like FluentValidation.NET, which allows you to do highly complex input validations on the server, even one layer below your Web/HTTP layer. Of course you would also want to validate client-side with something like jQuery validate.

I agree with other answers here that doing some security-level stuff at the server (controller action or razor) level is a little easier and a little more "trustworthy". But no one else here as mentioned the testability of MVVM. It's very easy to write unit tests around controller actions or other server-side code. That's not to say you can't unit/integration/UAT test MVVM apps, just that it requires more effort IMO.